# CRUD operations on nested one to many relationships in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have the following relationships between my tables:

```
             one-to-one                   one-to-many
```

ESReportTemplate<------------> SearchPropsObject<---->FacetProps

All my tables get created successfully and if I add an ESReportTemplate object, all the sub objects get added properly. But if I retrieve the SearchPropsObject ,modify a property of the same and do an update object on ESReportTemplate, the changes are NOT being reflected in the database.

My hbm files are as follows:

ESReportTemplate.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true" discriminator-value="ESReportTemplate" name="com.webnms.nms.esreport.ESReportTemplate" table="ESReportTemplate">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id column="ESTID" name="estId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
    <natural-id>
    <property column="NAME" length="100" name="name" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    </natural-id>
    <set name="esReports" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
                        <cache usage="read-write"/>
                    <key column="ESTID"/>
                    <one-to-many class="com.webnms.nms.esreport.ESReportObject" />
</set>
<one-to-one name="SearchPropsObject" class="com.webnms.nms.esreport.SearchPropsObject" cascade="all" lazy="false"></one-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SearchPropsObject.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true" discriminator-value="SearchPropsObject" name="com.webnms.nms.esreport.SearchPropsObject" table="SearchPropsObject">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
<id name="estId" type="long" column="ESTID">
               <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">ESReportTemplate</param>
            </generator>
</id>
<one-to-one name="ESReportTemplate" class="com.webnms.nms.esreport.ESReportTemplate" constrained="true" lazy="false"></one-to-one>  
<property column="REPORTTYPE" length="100" name="reportType" type="string"/>
<property column="PERSONALITYNAMES" length="500" name="personalityNames" type="string"/>
<property column="APPNAMES" length="500" name="appNames" type="string"/>
<property column="ENTITYNAMES" length="500" name="entityNames" type="string"/>
<set name="facets" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
                        <cache usage="read-write"/>
                    <key column="ESTID"/>
                    <one-to-many class="com.webnms.nms.esreport.FacetProps" />
</set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

FacetProps.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true" discriminator-value="FacetProps" name="com.webnms.nms.esreport.FacetProps" table="FacetProps">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id column="FID" name="facetId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
<many-to-one name="searchProps" class="com.webnms.nms.esreport.SearchPropsObject" fetch="select">
<column name="ESTID" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
<property column="FACETS" length="500" name="facets" type="string"/>
<property column="ISMULTILEVEL" length="100" name="isMultiLevel" type="boolean"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My code for update is as follows:

```
ESReportTemplate est = (ESReportTemplate)obj;
session.saveOrUpdate(est);
```

Note: session is created and managed internally by our application.

Any help is appreciated. I am not sure I am missing.

Comment: Can you show the code how you are updating

Comment: I suspect with `saveOrUpdate()` method, can you just try using `update()` method.

Comment: @Viji any error you are getting ?? see if the HQL is generated or not for ESReportTemplate when your updating the SearchPropsObject

Comment: @Amar, I don't see any specific error. I can enable spy log and check the update query that happens in the database. That should explain things.

Comment: @looser update() method also shows the same behavior

Comment: Okay can you make it clear here.. `But if I retrieve the SearchPropsObject ,modify a property of the same and do an update object on ESReportTemplate, the changes are NOT being reflected in the database.`  So you mean that you are modifiying `SearchPropsObject` and updating `ESReportTemplate` and they have `one-one` relationship is it correct ? if thats the case have you tried this `cascade="save-update"` in `ESReportTemplate` mapping file and `SearchPropsObject` as well

Comment: @looser yes your understanding is right. But I have specified cascade="all" in all my relationships , in that case, save-update option is also included right? Please correct me if I am wrong.